# Icicles find file in project

Tags: emacs, project, icicles

How can you find a file in a project (defined as everything under a single directory) using Icicles in Emacs?  The feature I am looking for is similar to that offerred by the [Projectile](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile) package.

The documentation [mentions that this is possible](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Support_for_Projects), but says nothing on how to actually do it.

The reason I want to do this with Icicles instead of Projectile is that I want to use Icicles completion features and not Projectile's ido-like interface.

Comment: I don't use Icicles myself, but have you considered marking the project directory in a Dired buffer, and then invoking [`icicles-search-dired-marked-recursive`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Search_Commands%2c_Overview#toc3) via `M-s M-s m`?

Comment: Projectile is completion-mechanism agnostic (meaning you're not required to use ido). It should be easy to integrate it with icicles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to find a file among your project files.  And the doc page you cite is the best place to start.  Which ways you choose can depend on how you define a project as a collection of files.

If, as you say, you define your project files as all of those in and under a single directory (i.e., recursively), then these are some ways to do what you want:

- Use command `icicle-locate` or `icicle-locate-file` for the project directory -- see [Find Files Anywhere, Without Knowing Where](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_File-Name_Input#toc11)
  .  You can cache the set of project file names for better performance -- see [Persistent Completions](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Persistent_Completions).

  Note that these commands, like all **Icicles** file-visiting commands, also let you search file *contents* -- match file name or contents or both.  See [Match File Names and File Content Too](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_File-Name_Input#toc8).
- As @Aaron suggested, you can open Dired for your project main directory, and then use one of the **Icicles** commands for the contents of the marked files:

  - `M-x M-s m` (command `icicles-search-dired-marked-recursive`) -- it uses [**Icicles** search](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Search_Commands%2c_Overview#toc3).
  - `M-+ C-F` (command `icicle-visit-marked-file-of-content-recursive`) -- it visits marked files whose content matches a search pattern.  (Again, see [Match File Names and File Content Too](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_File-Name_Input#toc8).
- Create *bookmarks* to Dired listings of your project directory.  They can have different sets of files marked or omitted.  If you use [**Bookmak+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/BookmarkPlus)
  then markings, omissions, and inserted subdirectories are all recorded as part of the bookmark.
- Use [**Dired+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/DiredPlus) for even more possibilities -- synergy among Dired, **Icicles** and **Bookmark+**.

  In particular, all of the things mentioned here, and more, are available from the **Dired+** menus.  (That will help you learn their keys.)

  In particular, see submenu ***Marked Here and Below***  of menu-bar menu ***Multiple*** (which deals with marked files).  It is the menu for acting on files anywhere below the current directory (no need to insert the subdirs etc.).